# xspace failing with long hyphen (---)?

Tags: spacing, xspace

The `xspace` package fails when used together with `---`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}

  \newcommand{\twosslvbf}{2 SS l (VBF)\xspace}

  \twosslvbf is OK.

  \twosslvbf --- not OK? % space between ")" and "-" missing

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way to repair this? (Or am I using an old version?)

Answer (score 3):

The hyphen is one of the "exceptions" (like full stop, comma...) where `\xspace` does *not* set a space. You can eliminate it from the predetermined list of exceptions through

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\xspaceremoveexception{-}
```

in the preamble.

Of course this might have other unwanted effects, for you mostly do *not* want a space before a hyphen. To correct this behaviour, I copy-paste from the `xspace` documentation the following trick which ensures that an en- and em-dash have a space after them while a hyphen doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\xspaceremoveexception{-}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@xspace@hook{%
\ifx\@let@token-%
\expandafter\@xspace@dash@i
\fi
}
\def\@xspace@dash@i-{\futurelet\@let@token\@xspace@dash@ii}
\def\@xspace@dash@ii{%
\ifx\@let@token-%
\else
\unskip
\fi
-%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\gm}{Grassmann\xspace}

\begin{document}
\gm is OK. % normal space

\gm-valued spinor works too. % no space, as it should.

\gm -- followed by en-sash % space

\gm --- Who was this guy? % space
\end{document}
```